# How can I Create Custom Controllers for Visualforce Page in Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce

How to Create Custom Controllers for Visualforce Page in Salesforce?

Comment: any apex class can be a custom controller

Comment: Hi Ethan, welcome to SFSE! Your question is asking for other people to write code for you, without presenting a real question or issue. SFSE is a Q&A forum where we look to help each other by asking and answering questions that are real problems or errors. Posting requests to write code for you will get closed. If you need assistance learning the Salesforce technical environment, I recommend you visit Trailhead and go through the [Trailhead Modules](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/modules), particularly the Introductory Visualforce modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this [video](http://www.jeet-singh.com/videos.php?salesforce-tutorial=Custom%20Controllers%20in%20Salesforce%20%7C%20Basics%20of%20Apex%20%7C%20Apex%20Fundamentals%20%7C%20by%20Jeet%20Singh&id=qh2w9wln9iw) for you on Creating Custom Controllers in Visualforce Page in Salesforce.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @Arshad Khan. This was helpful. Every concept is cleared in this video.